# SetTimeout executes faster than expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, timer

I am learning javascript:

I am currently trying to do a game where animals should spawn each random time, between one and two seconds, and then we could click on them and  make them dissapear.

I am facing a difficulty because I have added a SetTimeout to wait until the jump animation ends, to remove its CSS class to delete the animal.

However the animals only show first time, and then, the execution of the jump function goes quickly so then the animals do not show up.

I have tried to debug the program, first we see the animal on the same div which has been randomly calculated:

[image]

On the next step, we see that the animal appears on the second hole, and the debugger stills recording that the hole been used is the fifth:

[image]

It is in the next step when we see the div 2 been used:

[image]

And again the debugger stills saying that it is the div 2 been used when the animal spawns from 1:

[image]

In addition if I try to execute the program with the debugger the animals only show the first time and then they always hide. Plus in the console we see a lot of console.log with time and hole each second at once.

[image]

Here is the current code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Whack A Mole!</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Whack-a-mole! <span class="score">0</span></h1>
<button onClick="startGame()">Start!</button>

<div class="game">
    <div class="hole hole1">
        <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole2">
        <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole3">
        <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole4">
        <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole5">
        <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hole hole6">
        <div class="mole"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    const holes = document.querySelectorAll('.hole');
    const scoreBoard = document.querySelector('.score');
    const moles = document.querySelectorAll('.mole');

    let lastHole;

    function randomTime(min, max) {
        const time = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        console.log(time);
    }

    function randomHole(holes) {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * holes.length);
        const hole = holes[index];
        if (hole === lastHole) {
            console.log('We calculate a new hole!');
            return randomHole(holes);
        }
        lastHole = hole;
        return hole;
    }

    function jump() {
        let time = randomTime(1000, 2000);
        let hole = randomHole(holes);
        console.log(time, hole);
        hole.classList.add('up');
        setTimeout(() => {
            hole.classList.remove('up');
            debugger;
            jump();
        }, time);
    }

    jump();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose that it is the jump() function the one which behaves unexpectedly however, how could we spawn the animal, wait for the transition, and hide it, and then make a new one appear?.

style.css

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: #ffc600;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10rem;
  line-height:1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.score {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding:0 3rem;
  line-height:1;
  border-radius:1rem;
}

.game {
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.hole {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.hole:after {
  display: block;
  background: url(dirt.svg) bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  content:'';
  width: 100%;
  height:70px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom:-30px;
}

.mole {
  background:url('mole.svg') bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size:60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition:all 0.4s;
}

.hole.up .mole {
  top:0;
}
```

EDIT:

Thank you @Scott Marcus for your help I appreciate it.

I have tried the following code, I will just put the jump function:

```
<script>
    const holes = document.querySelectorAll('.hole');
    const scoreBoard = document.querySelector('.score');
    const moles = document.querySelectorAll('.mole');

    let lastHole;
    let timer = null;

    function randomTime(min, max) {
        const time = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        console.log(time);
    }

    function randomHole(holes) {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * holes.length);
        const hole = holes[index];
        if (hole === lastHole) {
            console.log('We calculate a new hole!');
            return randomHole(holes);
        }
        lastHole = hole;
        return hole;
    }

    function jump() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        let time = randomTime(1000, 2000);
        let hole = randomHole(holes);
        console.log(time, hole);
        hole.classList.add('up');
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            hole.classList.remove('up');
            debugger;
            jump();
        }, time);
    }

    jump();

</script>
```

I have discovered that if we scroll with the mouse wheel the animals spawn, in Opera:

[image]

However we have not put an evenetListener on the script.

In addition in Mozilla they do not show up at all:

[image]

Even if we see in the console how randomTime and randomHole is being calculated and shown.

How could we make the animals spawn?

I think the cause why they do not show is because the timers execute too fast, even if we save the last one, the last timer and clear it if it has not finished yet.

**Thank you for your help!!**

Answer (score 1):

Since your `jump` function contains the `setTimeout` and the timer's callback function makes a recursive call to `jump`, you have a scenario where a second call to `jump` can occur before the first timer has run or completed. This can cause multiple timer callback functions to become "stacked" up in the event queue and run, one immediately after the other. This is likely the behavior that you are seeing.

**You need to ensure that additional calls to `jump` don't initiate additional timers, which can cause the effect you are describing.**

You achieve this by ensuring that only one timer can ever be running at a time and that is accomplished by capturing the timer's unique identifier and making sure to cancel the last timer before starting a new one.

```
var timer = null; // This will hold the most recent timer's id

function jump() {
    clearTimeout(timer); // Cancel any previous timer

    let time = randomTime(1000, 2000);
    let hole = randomHole(holes);
    console.log(time, hole);
    hole.classList.add('up');

    // Capture a reference to the most recent timer
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
        hole.classList.remove('up');
        debugger;
        jump();
    }, time);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott Marcus for your kind help. I have tried to store the current timer in a variable and then crearTimeout as first jump's instruction, however they do not show in Mozilla at all, and in Opera they only show at first execution, then after the first one dissapears the others do not show up.

Comment: @Enoy Honestly, I haven't looked over all of your code. You most likely still have issues with other aspects of the code, but what I've shared here addresses the speeding up of the timers that you asked about.